# Why is the return type of a method, a class name in the below code of scala?

Tags: scala, data-structures, functional-programming

```
abstract class IntSet {
   def contains(x: Int): Boolean
   def incl(x: Int): IntSet
}
```

I'm learning Scala. Why is the return type of method `incl` a class name which is `IntSet`? What does this mean?

Comment: Your question is unclear. For example, why are you specifically asking about `incl`? The return type of `contains` is also a class, `Boolean`, do you understand *that*? Then why do you think there is any difference between the two?

Comment: Can you explain what `incl` is supposed to do? My guess is that it adds `x` to an `IntSet`.

Comment: @RichouHunter: well I did a quick search and found [this](https://github.com/mrhooray/scala-coursera/blob/master/practice/src/IntSet.scala) although here it is `include`, I guess it indeed adds the element to the `IntSet`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - I'm concerned about `IntSet` as it is the return type of `incl` method. My understanding here is that contains method takes a parameter (which is `Int` here) and returns a `Boolean` which is true or false. In this context, how does contains method return `IntSet`?

Comment: @RakeshKumar: You are asking why the return type of the `incl` method is a class. But the return type of the `contains` method is also a class, yet you seem perfectly fine with that. So, what makes the `incl` method special, so that the fact that its return type is a class confuses you, when at the same time the `contains` method's return type is also a class, and you are perfectly fine with that.

Comment: This should be part of the question: "how does contains method return IntSet", @RakeshKumar. And the answer is: it's an abstract method, therefore the how is irrelevant, only the declaration matters, the the concrete implementations of that will take care of the how.

Comment: As for the "why" in your question: you tell us why, it's *your* abstract class. Why did you made it like that? I don't think you are asking the right questions. Think a bit more about @JörgWMittag and my questions to you and reformulate yours.

Comment: Another question to you: are you familiar with abstract classes in languages like Java, C# or C++? It seems you lack that familiarity and is not stating that, this knowledge is essential in this context.

Comment: @pedrofurla You are right that I'm not much familiar with abstract classes and I'm learning them now. My first comment includes the statement "how does contains method return Intset" and I should have included it in the question instead of writing as a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually logic and functional programming languages are *declarative* (not per se enforced, but in most cases, a declarative style is advised). It means you do **not alter a datastructure**: you construct a **new one that is a modified original one**. So in a declarative language when you have an `IntSet` and you **add** an element, you do **not** add it to that `IntSet`, you construct a new `IntSet` that has all elements of the original `IntSet` and the one you add `x`.

So the reason why `incl` returns an `IntSet` is because the original `IntSet` is not modified, it constructs a new one.

Usually when a new `IntSet` is constructed, it will of course **not construct a complete new object**. Since the orignal `IntSet` is not supposed to change, it can **use sub-structures of the original `IntSet`**. Therefore declarative languages usually have their own set of dedicated data-structures, like for instance a [*finger tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree).

Take for instance [this implementation](https://github.com/mrhooray/scala-coursera/blob/master/practice/src/IntSet.scala) of an `IntSet`. What we see is:

```
object Empty extends IntSet {
  override def toString = "."
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean = false
  def include(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmpty(x, Empty, Empty)
  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet = other
}
```

So when we use the `Empty` `IntSet` object, and we `include` an element `x`, instead of altering the object, we construct a new `IntSet`: `NonEmpty(x,Empty,Empty)`. This `IntSet` contains `x`.